# How can I redirect url's with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a site with some url's :

```
www.example.com/nl-foo1.php
www.example.com/nl-foo2.php
www.example.com/nl-foo3.php
```

I changed the filenames to :

```
www.example.com/foo1.php
www.example.com/foo2.php
www.example.com/foo3.php
```

I want a user to user that gives in www.example.com/nl-foo1.php
to be redirected to www.example.com/foo1.php

I guess that can be done with htaccess? But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule as **topmost rule** in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^nl-(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: It works! I just had to put this rule on top, as you said! thx!